# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxxx\xxx\blog.php on line 36 1:00 am, January 1

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, post

I am trying to build a blog site with php and MongoDB.
I successfully built the homepage but in the comment page I get errors like this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function MongoId() in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyDoc\Kazma\comment.php on line 11.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $id = $_POST['article_id'];
    try {
        $mongodb = new Mongo();
        $collection = $mongodb->myblogsite->articles;
    }catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
        die('Failed to connect to MongoDB '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    $article = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => MongoId($id)));
    $comment = array(
        'name' => $_POST['commenter_name'],
        'email' => $_POST['commenter_email'],
        'comment' => $_POST['comment'],
        'posted_at' => new MongoDate()
    );
    $collection->update(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)),
        array('$push' => array('comments' => $comments)));
    header('Location: blog.php?id='.$id);
?>
```

But after i add new to this line: $article = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => MongoId($id)));`

It works fine. but whenever i try to comment it actually throws the above error

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\xxx\blog.php on line 36.

I don't know what to do again. here is the blog.php code:

```
<?php 
$id = $_GET['id'];
try{
    $connection = new Mongo();
    $database = $connection->selectDB('myblogsite');
    $collection = $database->selectCollection('articles');
} catch(MongoConnectionException $e){
    die("failed to connect to database ". $e->getMessage());
}
$article = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId($id)));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>My Blog Site</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contentarea">
    <div id="innercontentarea">
        <h1><?php echo $article['title']; ?></h1>
        <p><?php echo $article['content']; ?></p>
        <div id="comment-section">
            <?php if (!empty($article['comments'])) : ?>
                <h3>Comments</h3>
                <?php foreach ($article['comments'] as $comment) :
                    echo $comment['name'] . ' says...'; ?>
                <p><?php echo $comment['comment']; ?></p>
                <span>
                    ***<?php echo date('g:i a, F j', $comment['posted_at']-> sec); ?>***
                </span><br/><br/><br/>
            <?php endforeach;
            endif; ?>
            <h3>Post your comment</h3>
            <form action="comment.php" method="post">
                <span class="input-label">Name</span>
                <input type="text" name="commenter_name" class="comment-input" />
                <br/><br/>
                <span class="input-label">Email</span>
                <input  type="text" name="commenter-email" class="comment-input" />
                <br/><br/>
                <textarea name="comment" rows="5"></textarea><br/><br/>
                <input type="hidden" name="article_id" value="<?php echo $article['_id']; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Save" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I guess `$comment['posted_at']-> sec` this is the cause. `$comment['posted_at']` seems to be no object, therefor there is no property `sec`. Try to `var_dump( $comment)` and look what data type `$comment['posted_at]` is.

Comment: Also: There is a space between `->` and `sec`